# PHPunit refactoring read file to EOF test to function

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, refactoring, eof

I am new to TDD and PHPUnit so please forgive me if my test function logic makes no sense.

I have a test function called test_read_to_end_of_file_is_reached which passes green as it's written in my inputTest class, approving that it reads to end of file.

I am trying to refactor the read/open part into a function in my Vendors model called readFile

Originally, **InputTest** class

```
<?php

class InputTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase{

    protected $vendors;

    public function setUp(){
        $this->vendors = new \App\Models\Vendors;
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_that_input_file_exists(){
        $this->assertFileExists($this->vendors->getFileName());
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_read_to_end_of_file_is_reached(){
        $fileName = $this->vendors->getFileName();
        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
        // loop until end of file
        while(!feof($file)){
            // read one character at a time
            $temp = fread($file, 1);
        }

        $this->assertTrue(feof($file));
        //close file
        fclose($file);
    }
```

My attempt to separate it into a function

**Vendors** class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
class Vendors
{
    protected $fileName = "app/DataStructures/input.txt";

    public function setFileName($fileName){
        $this->fileName = trim($fileName);
    }

    public function getFileName(){
        return trim($this->fileName);
    }

    public function readFile(){
        $fileName = $this->getFileName();
        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

        // loop until end of file
        while(!feof($file)){
            // read one character at a time
            $temp = fread($file, filesize($fileName));
            var_dump($temp);
        }
        return $file;
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

my refactored test:

```
    /** @test */
    public function test_read_to_end_of_file_is_reached(){
        $fileName = $this->vendors->getFileName();
        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
        $this->assertTrue(feof($this->vendors->readFile()));
        //close file
        fclose($file);
    }
```

This all works, I'm just not sure whether I can simplify the test more.
which will eventually allow me to build upon reading the text file and parsing line by line based on what is read to reproduce the contents on the console.

Comment: You should be testing the functionality of the method and that it does what you want (read a file), your changing the code to suit the test and returning the file pointer which does not make sense. Also you now got dead code as your returning before closing the pointer.

Comment: You can mock php functions to return different values when invoked, like you could mock fopen, fread to fail or feof to return true etc, handling breakage is what you ment to be testing if your trying to get coverage, though I dont see conditions so its overkill.

Comment: Plus you're test should be in VendorsTest case..

Comment: I was struggling of thinking up a condition for an assertion to match readFile, it's not quite assertFileIsReadable(). But I agree it's overkill, I may just write out the readFile function without a test.

Comment: You should test it, if it's going to fail it will be on fopen, so the idea would be to handle that like throwing an exception or returning false, then test for them. so one test would be good and one bad but both pass,. it would then lead you on to adding a check in getFileName that it exists or use realpath etc if its empty return false then in your read file method you can check if $fileName is empty and return false etc.